# Sub Query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an SQL Query as given below

```
SELECT ui.PageStyleCss
 FROM UserImages ui 
 WHERE ui.UserImageId IN 
  ( SELECT inv.UserImageId 
   FROM Invitation inv
   JOIN InviteeEmails invEmails ON 
   inv.InviteID = invEmails.InviteID
   WHERE invEmails.InviteGUID = @InviteGUID
  )
```

How can I write this in LINQ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more info on what your table structure looks like?

Answer (score 3):

My wild guess is that you're using LINQ to SQL. It would be nice if you mentioned this, along with details of your model. Guessing at its structure...

```
var q = from ui in Context.UserImages
        where ui.Invitations.Any(i => i.InviteeEmails.Any(e => e.InviteGuid = inviteGuid))
        select ui.PageStyleCss;
```

Comment: +1 awesome, even though this question was so specific this helped me out! =)

Answer (score 0):

```
from ui in db.UserImages
where (from inv in db.Invitations
       join invEmails from InviteeEmails 
           on inv.InviteId equals invEmails.InviteId
       where invEmails.InviteGUID == inviteGUID
       select inv.UserImageId).Contains(ui.UserImageId)
select ui.PageStyleCss
```

(not sure if it compiles or not)

I have to assume there's a better way...this is pretty much a direct translation.